# blueimp - PHP file upload drops file extension

Tags: php, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I'm using blueimp/jquery-file-upload for file upload. My back-end language is PHP. While user uploaded their docs few files were uploaded without any extension. When i see my file upload tracker those document names are "blob". But it is not possible different users uploading files with same name. So it should be something handled inside bluimp source code. blueimp should change some type of file names to "blob" and those documents are uploaded without any extension in server.  Does anyone have an idea about this?